# Source option 6 is no longer supported. Use 7 or later

Tags: maven

I'm getting the following error when I try to run configurations on my pom.xml file. Any suggestions?

```
Source option 6 is no longer supported. Use 7 or later.
```

Comment: What JDK are you using?

Comment: @JFMeier Version - 1.8.0.221

Comment: Then please add the POM and the console output of the build.