# GitHub Actions Continuous Deployment of a Clojure project returning "Source option 5 is no longer supported. Use 6 or later". How to fix it?

Tags: maven, clojure, compilation, github-actions, pom.xml

I am trying to build a GitHub Actions workflow as a Continuous Deployment procedure on this [forked repository](https://github.com/tallyfor/flow) of a Clojure project.

The [process](https://github.com/tallyfor/flow/actions/runs/3912019706/jobs/6686115354)  goes well until it reaches this point:

```bash
Error:  Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) on project flow: Compilation failure: Compilation failure: 
Error:  Source option 5 is no longer supported. Use 6 or later.
Error:  Target option 1.5 is no longer supported. Use 1.6 or later.
Error:  -> [Help 1]
```

Usually, other problems in Stack Overflow related to this error message involve tweaking the `pom.xml` (see examples: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67837139/source-option-5-is-no-longer-supported-use-6-or-later-android-studio), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59685437/java-maven-project-source-option-5-is-no-longer-supported-use-6-or-later), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68068836/how-to-fix-gradle-error-source-option-5-is-no-longer-supported-use-6-or-later), [4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58055558/source-option-6-is-no-longer-supported-use-7-or-later), [5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53034953/error-source-option-5-is-no-longer-supported-use-6-or-later-on-maven-compile), [6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61860989/another-maven-source-option-6-is-no-longer-supported-use-7-or-later)).

However, since this is a Clojure project managed by Leiningen, there *is not such a file* initially. The `pom.xml` is generated after `lein install` (and other command) is executed. Clojure is a hosted language on the JVM, after all.

As a side note, I am not sure why this project has `:java-source-paths` ([link](https://github.com/tallyfor/flow/blob/58b8f298d33596d32cdef16201e44f12474ca9c4/project.clj#L8)) instead of `:source-paths`. Not sure if this aspect is related to the problem discussed here.

How to fix it?

Comment: First define the version of the maven-compiler-plugin (https://maven.apache.org/plugins/) and define `<maven.compiler.source>..</maven.compiler.source>` + `<maven.compiler.target>..</maven.compiler.target>` or JDK9+ use `<maven.compiler.release>..</maven.compiler.release>`...

Comment: If you cannot fix the Pom.xml, you can override with system properties.  See https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/compile-mojo.html